# Using Max and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM 
(SELECT
 moncallAdd.FirstListing,
  max (Dateadd(MINUTE, moncalladd.addtime,
         DateAdd(Day,moncalladd.adddate,'12/31/1899'))) as AddStart,
 DATEADD(MINUTE, mOnCallAdd.StartOnCallTime,
         DATEADD(DAY, mOnCallAdd.StartOnCallDate, '12/31/1899')) AS OnCallStart,
 DATEADD(MINUTE, mOnCallAdd.duration,
         DATEADD(MINUTE, mOnCallAdd.StartOnCallTime,
                 DATEADD(DAY, mOnCallAdd.StartOnCallDate, '12/31/1899'))) AS OnCallEnd,
 'Added' AS Activity
 FROM
 mdr.dbo.mOnCallAdd
  WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, mOnCallAdd.StartOnCallTime,
 DATEADD(DAY, mOnCallAdd.StartOnCallDate, '12/31/1899')) < GETDATE() 
AND 
 DATEADD(MINUTE, mOnCallAdd.duration,
         DATEADD(MINUTE, mOnCallAdd.StartOnCallTime,
                 DATEADD(DAY, mOnCallAdd.StartOnCallDate, '12/31/1899'))) >  GETDATE()
AND  mOnCallAdd.SchedName = 'capital neph') a 

LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
 moncallDelete.FirstListing,
 DATEADD(MINUTE, mOnCallDelete.StartOnCallTime,
         DATEADD(DAY, mOnCallDelete.StartOnCallDate, '12/31/1899')) AS OnCallStart,
 DATEADD(MINUTE, mOnCallDelete.duration,
         DATEADD(MINUTE, mOnCallDelete.StartOnCallTime,
                 DATEADD(DAY, mOnCallDelete.StartOnCallDate, '12/31/1899'))) AS OnCallEnd,
'Deleted' AS Activity
FROM
   mdr.dbo.mOnCallDelete
  WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, mOnCallDelete.StartOnCallTime,
 DATEADD(DAY, mOnCallDelete.StartOnCallDate, '12/31/1899')) < GETDATE() 
AND 
 DATEADD(MINUTE, mOnCallDelete.duration,
         DATEADD(MINUTE, mOnCallDelete.StartOnCallTime,
                 DATEADD(DAY, mOnCallDelete.StartOnCallDate, '12/31/1899'))) >  GETDATE()
AND  mOnCallDelete.SchedName = 'capital neph') b 
ON a.FirstListing = b.FirstListing
and a.oncallstart = b.oncallstart
and a.oncallend = b.oncallend
group by FirstListing
```

and when I try to run this query I get the following error:

> Ambiguous column name 'FirstListing'.

and when I try `group by moncalladd.firstlisting`, I get this error:

> The column prefix 'moncalladd' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

and when I try to `group by a.firstlisting` I get this error:

> Column 'a.AddStart' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I don't know what I'm missing, but obviously it's something simple. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: All your error codes are self explanatory...

Comment: Why are you trying to `group by FirstListing` in the first place? This query should work without that `group by`.

Comment: column names are case sensitive.

Comment: @Johnny Where do you infer that from?

Comment: @Johnny Not necessarily.

Comment: your calling this: moncalladd.firstlisting  and your calling this mdr.dbo.mOnCallAdd   i guess i was assuming moncalladd.firstlisting is referring to a column in the mOnCallAdd table.
edit: i meant table names are case sensitive.

Comment: Hi Doug, after the join, how do you want the data grouped by? Looking at the select list of a.*, I don't think you need any GROUP BY clause; unless you would like perform an aggregate operation for any of the fields. If you can let us know what kinda data you would like to display, we can help you how to construct the groupby clause.

Answer (score 1):

The moment you use a `GROUP BY` clause, you have to specify, for **every** column in the `SELECT` list, whether you want a group-aggregate operator (eg `SUM`, `MAX`) applied to it, or whether it is to form part of the group **key** - this latter is done by including it in the `GROUP BY` list.

Since you are `SELECT`ing all 5 columns of your subquery `a`, you have to say what is to happen to every single one, when the grouping operation is performed.

It's not immediately obvious to me that your query is correct, so I can't say what the solution is, but it *may* be simply a metter of explicitly listing all the columns of `a` inthe `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: AakashM, I have tried using the columns of a. and also of listing the mdr.dbo.moncalladd, and none of that works. Here's what I get when I try it with the a columns:Server: Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid column name 'StartOnCallDate'.
Server: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'StartOnCallTime'.
Server: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'StartOnCallDate'.
Server: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'StartOnCallTime'.
Server: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Duration'.

Comment: IF your query runs correctly without the `GROUP BY` clause at all, it should also run with the addition of `GROUP BY FirstListing, AddStart, OnCallStart, OnCallEnd, Activity`, since those are the columns of `a`. But I can't say if that will return thedata you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify your derived table `a` to have its own GROUP BY. You've got a `MAX()` in there that forces you to include a `GROUP BY`. See Lines 4 thorugh 16 on my Pastie.

2.Modify your SELECT and GROUP BY on the first and last lines of your query:

```
SELECT a.FirstListing, a.AddStart, a.OnCallStart, a.OnCallEnd, a.Activity
FROM ---your big derived table
GROUP BY  a.FirstListing, a.AddStart, a.OnCallStart, a.OnCallEnd, a.Activity
```

Here's how your code should look: http://pastie.org/2428802

Comment: P. I tried that and get this error:Column 'mdr.dbo.mOnCallAdd.FirstListing' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function and there is no GROUP BY clause.

Comment: P. I am now getting this error: Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. and I copied your code.